How to efficiently perform parallel file search using pathlib `glob` in Python for large directory structures?
I'm working on a Python project where I need to search for specific files across a very large directory structure. Currently, I'm using the glob (or rglob) method from the pathlib module, but it is quite slow due to the extensive number of files and directories.
Here's a simplified version of my current code:
from pathlib import Path

base_dir = Path("/path/to/large/directory")
files = list(base_dir.rglob("ind_stat.zpkl"))

This works, but it's too slow because it has to traverse through a massive number of directories and files. Ideally, I'd like to divide the directory traversal work across multiple threads or processes to improve performance. Are there optimizations or alternative libraries/methods that could help improve the performance?

Honestly, I'd probably look at wrapping something like https://crates.io/crates/jwalk with PyO3 if you really do need all the speed you can get.

Another, quicker and easier way, if you know /path/to/large/directory won't change very often, is to only do the traversal once and save the list of files as e.g. an SQLite database, and query it.

note that parallel file search only makes sense on a slow network filesystem which permits concurrent queries. But then, most likely, there is a more efficient API for that. When searching on local FS, simple rglob will be faster almost regardless of the storage type. Massive concurrency without benchmarking is too often a pessimization.

You don't mention your filesystem, or the disk type/configuration, or the volume of data, or the number of files, or the depth/layout of the files, or the current/desired performance...

@LogicDaemon "When searching on local FS, simple rglob will be faster almost regardless of the storage type" – what do you base this on? Faster than what? Given all of the bits, globbing included, used by rglob are written in Python, one could likely easily come up with a faster, less generic function to find all ind_stat.zpkls.

@AKX that is based on 2 assumptions mostly: 1. The interface between the storage system and the RAM is sequential (SATA or PCIe or whatever). 2. The CPU is fast enough to handle all that IO using a single core. The second assumption is not always true, but in cases it's false the multiprocessing overhead is also much more significant. The rglob you mention doesn't actually do any heavy processing in python code. It uses os.scandir under the hood which is pretty fast. Also see https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/408687/436501

@LogicDaemon If rglob doesn't do heavy processing, it's funny how it's possible to implement OP's problem 1.8x faster than rglob then (see my answer)! Secondly, since this is actually not reading the actual (big) data off the disk, I'd imagine the OS has a lot of the FS structures for the directories etc. already cached, so storage system overheads wouldn't come much into play there.

@AKX my original comment was about parallel search, which was in the question. And as SIGHUP example shows, it's worse than your variant. It's still a surprise to me that rglob is so noticeably slow, thank you for opening my eyes :)

@LogicDaemon I still do believe that a kernel could service multiple opendir and getdirentries calls for different user-land threads in parallel. Python's threads are of course a different beast due to the GIL.

@AKX I agree that kernel does. But the overhead due to process creation to work around the GIL and following synchronization is almost never worth it in cpython for local directories operations (it's worth it for relatively large files).

You may as well delete your question if you aren't going to respond to requests for clarification or upvote/accept any answers that folk have kindly offered.

Empirically, on my Mac, in a directory tree that has 73,429 files and 3,315 directories (and 3 files named Snap.wav):
~/Samples $ pwd
/Users/akx/Samples
~/Samples $ find . -type f | wc -l
   73429
~/Samples $ find . -type d | wc -l
    3315

a trivial os.walk() based implementation is 1.8x as fast as rglob:
import os
import pathlib

base_path = pathlib.Path("/Users/akx/Samples")
file_to_find = "Snap.wav"


def find_snaps_rglob():
    paths = []
    for path in base_path.rglob(file_to_find):
        paths.append(path)
    return paths


def find_snaps_walk():
    paths = []
    for dp, dn, fn in os.walk(base_path):
        for f in fn:
            if f == file_to_find:
                paths.append(pathlib.Path(os.path.join(dp, f)))
    return paths


assert sorted(find_snaps_rglob()) == sorted(find_snaps_walk())

name='find_snaps_rglob' iters=10 time=1.622 iters_per_sec=6.17
name='find_snaps_walk' iters=20 time=1.740 iters_per_sec=11.49

Implementing the walking with a stack and os.scandir() makes things a tiny bit faster still (iters_per_sec=12.98), but this likely doesn't take e.g. symlinks and errors into account like walk or rglob might.
def find_snaps_walk_manually():
    paths = []
    stack = [base_path]
    while stack:
        current = stack.pop()
        for child in os.scandir(current):
            if child.is_dir():
                stack.append(child)
            elif child.name == file_to_find:
                paths.append(pathlib.Path(child.path))
    return paths

I also gave a shot at wrapping the Rust walkdir and jwalk crates with PyO3 – they weren't much faster than find_snaps_walk_manually (about 13.14/13.34 RPS).

yep  - afaik, scandir was a late implementation that would use OS interactive API´s rather than just getting all results eagerly from os.walk. In pathlib, I think Path.iterdir makes use of it. It should work fine with multi-threading (even GILocked Python multithreading)

glob._Globber (which is what underpins Path.rglob()) also uses scandir. But given that even the Rust-based impls are approximately as fast, I think we've about reached the limit of what the underlying synchronous syscalls can push out to userspace. The next step would be something like io_uring getdents...


Are there optimizations or alternative libraries/methods that could help improve the performance?

Yes - upgrading to a newer Python version should provide a substantial performance improvement. Python 3.13 (currently in beta) includes the most speedups.
(I tried to provide this answer already but several SO moderators jumped down my throat. If they do so again I won't bother providing any support for pathlib on SO henceforth.)

Good comment! I tried my examples on 3.13b0 and rglob is significantly faster than it had been in 3.12, but find_snaps_walk_manually still narrowly wins (13.13 ips vs 12.19 ips).
